# ASP.net 5 preview templates are missed in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, .net-framework-version

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and have installed the latest Web Essentials update and also have installed DotnetCore version. But when I create a new asp.net project, only asp 4 templates like in the image are available

[create form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQaQc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no ASP.NET 5 anymore. It has [officially been renamed to ASP.NET Core 1.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx).

You seem to have missed that announcement, which would have made the selections in Visual Studio more obvious. When you choose File > New Project..., you get to a dialog that gives you a choice to go with `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)`, `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)` or `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)`. This is the dialog before the one you have posted a screenshot of.

> **NOTE:** In order to see all 3 of these options, you need to choose at least .NET Framework 4.5 from the dropdown.

The last two options are for the new ASP.NET Core 1.0 framework. The first of which is to run on the .NET Core library (cross-platform) and the last which is for the .NET Framework 4.6.1 library (which is not cross-platform).

[image: New Project Dialog]

Of course, if you choose `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)` , you get a regular MVC 5 or Web API 2 application.