# Where do I register IMemoryCache in my ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET web application that I created from Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. The .NET Framework is 4.6.1.

I have no idea which version of ASP.NET my web application is using ASP.NET MVC 4? ASP.NET MVC 5? It's not mentioned anywhere.

I'm trying to register `IMemoryCache` service (from `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`) into my Microsoft Unity container. However, anything I found about it on Google refers to adding `services.AddCaching()` in a `Startup.cs` file.

I don't have a `Startup.cs` file. I only see `Global.asax`. Furthermor, all my custom dependencies are registered within `UnityConfig.cs` which was provided when installing the NuGet package `Unity.Mvc` which is a Microsoft Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET by Microsoft.

Any help appreciated.

Edit:

Here's a screenshot of my project:

[image]

Comment: Is this in MVC 6? Do you have a config.json file in your solution?

Comment: Like i said in my question. I have no idea what version of ASP.NET MVC that Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition created for me.

Comment: In case you missed [the announcement](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx), there is no longer an ASP.NET 5. Which type of project you have depends on what project type you chose to create...Visual Studio 2015 supports both the legacy MVC stack and MVC Core...I can't help you there.

Comment: Thats the new ASP.Core framework.

Comment: Answer the second question please.

Comment: @Oluwafemi I updated question with a screenshot of my project with what files I have. There's no config.json

Comment: The directories you have in App_Start seem rather odd, did you drag those in there accidentally?

Comment: The bootstrap library rearranged everything when I installed it. So I just continued with the structure it provided. I added "ActionAttributes", "Services" and "Utilites. The "Controller" folder was initially at the root of the project. The bootstrap thing moved it to App_Start. So I just put all my stuff in there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you are referring to are part of the ASP.Net Core (ASP.Net 5)

In the new version you no longer have a Global.asax file, you have a new Startup processed defined in a Startup class. Also, DI is standard, so things work in a different way now. So either upgrade to the latest version of ASP.Net or apply use the DI solutions for the older version:

[RESOLVING DEPENDENCIES IN ASP.NET MVC 5 USING UNITY CONTAINER](https://debugmode.net/2014/08/28/resolving-dependencies-in-asp-net-mvc-5-using-unity-container/)

Also the package you are using is for the new ASP.NET version.

[Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html#application-anatomy)

Comment: I do not see a "Startup.cs" file. I only have a "Global.asax" file.

Comment: Well that's because like I said you are using a template from the "old" ASP.NET not the new one, which is ASP.NET Core. In the new version you don't have Global.asax anymore.

Comment: There's no option in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition to create a web application using the new ASP.NET.

Comment: In that case refer to you have to look at the documentation for the older version: https://debugmode.net/2014/08/28/resolving-dependencies-in-asp-net-mvc-5-using-unity-container/

Comment: There is an option in the New Project dialog to create ASP.NET Core applications. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38209676/181087).

Answer (score 10):

In .NET Core AddMemoryCache Extensions looks like this:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>());
```

So in .Net Framework you can use something like this (for Autofac):

```
builder.RegisterType<MemoryCache>().As<IMemoryCache>().SingleInstance();
```

UPD: However `MemoryCache`dependends on `IOptions<>` you should register it too:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsManager<>)).As(typeof(IOptions<>)).SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsManager<>)).As(typeof(IOptionsSnapshot<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsMonitor<>)).As(typeof(IOptionsMonitor<>)).SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsFactory<>)).As(typeof(IOptionsFactory<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsCache<>)).As(typeof(IOptionsMonitorCache<>)).SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Unity, you can do something similar like this
in UnityConfig.cs

```
var memoryCache = new MemoryCacheService(new MemoryCacheOptions());
            container.RegisterInstance<IMemoryCache>(memoryCache);
```

create your MemoryCacheService

```
public class MemoryCacheService : MemoryCache
    {
        public MemoryCacheService(IOptions<MemoryCacheOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(optionsAccessor)
        {
        }
    }
```

yourcontroller

```
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCacheService;
public yourcontroller(IMemoryCache memoryCacheService)
{
            _memoryCacheService = memoryCacheService;
        }

    public IHttpActionResult AddCacheItem(string cacheKey)
            {
                _memoryCacheService.Set(cacheKey, DateTime.Now.Ticks );
                var temp = _memoryCacheService.Get(cacheKey);
                return Ok(temp);
            }
```

Comment: I Think it's missing the MemoryCacheOptions class

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a problem with IMemoryCache. I have framework version 4.5.2. try the below step.

First, install below NuGet packages for .net framework 4.5.2 and MVC
[Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions --version 1.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/1.1.2)

[Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory --version 1.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/1.1.2)

After installing those packages please below the line in the AutofacConfig file

In .Net Framework you can use something like this (for Autofac):

```
builder.RegisterType<MemoryCache>().As<IMemoryCache>().SingleInstance();
```

However MemoryCachedependends on IOptions<> you should register it too:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OptionsManager<>)).As(typeof(IOptions<>)).SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the below link, which i think will help you.

[Setting Up the Unity Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx)

Comment: This does not help me at all. I know how to register dependencies with Microsoft Unity. I simply don't know how to register IMemoryCache from Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory